# Figures in Latex/Lyx

Tags: graphics, books, draw

Does anyone know which program was used for figures in Thomas' calculus book or in Stewart's calculus book? Particularly 3D figures for example in double integrals chapter (for example figure: the volume of the region enclosed by two paraboloids)

[image]

Is there any template for the page to look like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! I do not know what the author used but you can create such plots with `pgfplots`. The page layout resembles a bit what you get with the [`tufte-book` class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf).

Comment: @JohnB before posting a new question, could you consider accepting the answers to your old questions, if you find it useful?